# Double column css layout not overing each other bottom space

Tags: html, css, layout

Hi i'm trying to make a simple 2 col layout(it's a table conversion actually) and have a problem.
HTML:

```
<div class="obj_container" style="margin-top: 120px;">
        <div class="obj_title">
        Title:
        </div>
        <div id="obj">
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.obj_container {
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

.obj_title {
    width: 60px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.obj {
    width: 820px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

The problem is that when the text inside  is more than 1 line it will go under the  even if i specified both divs' widths; a solution may be to specify both divs' heights but that wouldn't adapt dynamically to the content.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `<div id="obj">`, but then `.obj`.

Change to using `<div class="obj">`.

As an aside, you're trying to contain the floats in `.obj_container`, so `clear: both` isn't what you need. Replace it with `overflow: hidden`, or use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Answer (score 2):

This should be

```
.obj_container {
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="obj_container" style="margin-top: 120px;">
        <div class="obj_title">
        Title:
        </div>
        <div id="obj">
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        Bla Bla Bla<br />
        </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.obj_container {
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.obj_title {
    width: 60px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.obj {
    width: 820px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```